# Even and odd solutions to Schrödinger equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential

There's a problem in Griffiths' QM text that has you find the allowed energies for a particle in an infinite potential well with a dirac delta potential at $x=0$. In solving this problem, we should look for even and odd solution separately.

One worked solution I've seen uses two wave functions,

$\psi (x) = A \cos k x + B \sin k x$

$\psi (x) = - A \cos k x + B \sin k x$

for the *even* solutions and

$\psi (x) = A \cos k x + B \sin k x$

$\psi (x) =  A \cos k x - D \sin k x$

for the *odd* ones.

Edit: I think my problem is best rephrased "where do the even/odd solutions come up?". I went back and did it all just assuming a solution of $\psi (x) = A \cos k x + B \sin k x$ and $\psi (x) = C \cos k x + D \sin k x$ and only came out with the *even* solutions. I have no idea how we arrive at the odd ones. The condition that the cosine coefficient should be 0 makes no sense to me.

Comment: It'd be better if you showed your complete derivation of the solution. Otherwise it's only possible to _guess_ where you lost half of the solutions.

Comment: Could you please state the original question? Without context, one is hard to infer what even and odd solutions mean here..

Answer (score 5):

Even and odd solutions come up as follows.
Suppose $\psi_1(x)$ is a solution to 
$$
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2\psi_1(x)}{dx^2}+V(x)\psi_1(x)=E_1\psi_1(x)
$$
and make the change $x\to -x$ every where.  Then 
$$
\frac{d}{d(-x)}=-\frac{d}{dx}\, ,\qquad \frac{d^2}{d(-x)^2}
=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}
$$
so we get
$$
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2\psi_1(-x)}{dx^2}+V(-x)\psi_1(-x)=E_1\psi_1(-x)
$$
If you potential is symmetric, then $V(-x)=V(x)$ and you can see that
$\psi_2(x):=\psi_1(-x)$ is also solution to the problem for the same potential.  Since $\psi_1(x)$ and $\psi_2(x)$ have the *same* eigenvalue $E_1$, then it is easy to see that
$$
\phi(x)=A\psi_1(x)+B\psi_2(x)=A\psi_1(x)+B\psi_1(-x)
$$
is also a solution with energy $E_1$.
The even solution is the choise $A=B$: in this case
$\phi_+(x)=A (\psi_1(x)+\psi_1(-x))=\phi_+(-x)$, defining an even function. The odd solution $\phi_-(x)$ is obtained using $B=-A$; it satisfies $\phi_-(-x)=-\phi_-(x)$.  Thus, in a symmetric potential for which $V(x)=V(-x)$, it is always possible to find even or odd solutions to the problem.

In your specific case, you're better off starting with
$$
\psi(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
A\sin(k(x+L))&\hbox{if }x<0\, ,\\
B\sin(k(x-L))&\hbox{if }x>0\, .\end{array}\right.
$$
This form guarantees $\psi(-L)=\psi(L)=0$ if your walls are at $x=\pm L$.  You can probably expand the argument of each sine to get a sine and a cosine combination but this form makes it obvious that you will satisfy the boundary conditions.

The parity of the solution will come in when you relate $A$ and $B$.  For instance, taking $x\to -x$ changes $A\sin(k(x+L))\to A\sin(k(-x+L))=-A(\sin(k(x-L))$ while $B\sin(k(x-L))\to -B\sin(k(x+L))$ 
so the even solution is with $B=-A$.  You then need to find $k$ using the discontinuity of the derivatives

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: @Astrum added a discussion of even/odd solutions at the top.  Let me know if this is suitable.