# Proof $\langle p\rangle=0$ if and only if potential is symmetric

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum, potential, parity

I came across a statement where $\langle p\rangle=0$ if and only if the potential in a Hamiltonian is symmetric, i.e. $V(-x)=V(x)$. It made some sort of sense to me comparing with the particle in a box, and quantum SHO systems. However, I failed to find some sort of a generalized theoretical proof for this statement. How do I proceed to think about it?

Comment: The claim is false. $\langle p\rangle$ depends on which state you take the expectation value. There are infinitely many states for which $\langle p\rangle\neq0$, regardless of the symmetry of the potential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the potential is an even function, then the wavefunction has a defined parity and is either even or odd. This is a classic result of QM and the Time-independent schrodinger equation to which there are many proofs online.
for example see answer here:
[Even and odd solutions to Schrödinger equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/315474/even-and-odd-solutions-to-schr%C3%B6dinger-equation)

mathematically:

if $V(x)=V(-x)$ then $\psi(-x)=\pm\psi(x)$

if so, what is the parity of this quantity?: $$\psi\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}$$

then proving $\langle\hat{p}\rangle =0$ is simple and follows from the definition of the momentum operator.

Comment: What about the opposite direction? (If and *only if*)

Comment: the potential being symmetric does not imply the wavefunction has defined parity. It only means that the wavefunction can be chosen to have defined parity (i.e., there is a simultaneous eigenbasis of parity and H; you are not forced to use this basis, but you can if you want to). The claim in the OP is false as written; the correct claim is that one can *choose* states such that $\langle p\rangle=0$.

Answer (score 2):

The converse is not true in general.  Don’t forget the correspondence theorem $\tfrac{d}{dt}\left\langle x \right\rangle =\tfrac{1}{m}\left\langle p \right\rangle $, which follows from $[H,X]=\tfrac{1}{2m}[{{P}^{2}},X]=\tfrac{i}{m}P$ .   If the particle is really trapped over long run, then both sides must be zero, whether the well is symmetric or not.   But nothing keeps $\left\langle x \right\rangle $ from oscillating in the short run.